# Python connection with a Device through serial port

Tags: python, serial-port

I need help with a python code to connect with a Router or a Switch via serial port. I use pycharm from a Windows terminal.

This is what I tried:

```py
import keyboard

ser = serial.Serial(port="COM1", baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

while True:
    ser.write('You got connected\r\n'.encode('Ascii'))
    receive = ser.readline()
    print(receive.decode('Ascii'))
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        print('User need to quit the app.')
        break

ser.close()
```

Tried and I got errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full traceback you got.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get ?
This would be very helpful if you could copy/paste your errors in here.